# 'undefined reference to' Linker errors with latest LLVM from git (3.9.0svn) on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, macos, c++11, llvm, linker-errors

Prior to my Macbook Pro motherboard failure I was working on a programming language of mine with Flex, Bison, and LLVM.  I honestly don't recall the version of LLVM I was linking against at the time (I will try to find this out after I salvage the data from the drive), but I do know that the latest version I'm using now from git (clang version 3.9.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 7658b570923dcdfaaec04d837b7e8862eff895f8) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4edb79d2d975816fee53b814703812b2287ed455)) had a few minor API changes I had to compensate for.

I actually ended up replacing my Macbook with an MSI GS40 and chose Arch Linux as my new main OS.  So my two primary variables here are Linux vs OS X and the different versions of LLVM/Clang/GCC involved.

I built LLVM the same way I did on OS X:

```
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git llvm/tools/clang
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang-tools-extra.git llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra
git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git llvm/projects/compiler-rt
git clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxx.git llvm/projects/libcxx
git clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxxabi.git llvm/projects/libcxxabi

mkdir build_llvm
cd build_llvm && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=prefix=/usr/local/llvm ../llvm
make
make install
```

I didn't realize until this time around that it makes a "prefix=" folder as the documentation for LLVM makes it appear as though this is the command (In reality you would omit the `prefix=`).  So I just manually moved the output `llvm` folder to a new location and exported the `include` directory in my .bash_profile.

I have the project compiling now, but I am unable to link with LLVM and receive the following errors:

```
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `CodeGenContext':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:59: undefined reference to `llvm::sys::getProcessTriple()'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `CodeGenContext::handleError(int, int, llvm::StringRef, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:87: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `CompilationUnit::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2200: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `NamespaceDeclarationNode::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2220: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `UsingDeclarationNode::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2226: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `Int8Node::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2237: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o:/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2242: more undefined references to `llvm::Twine::str() const' follow
clang-3.9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'mycompiler' failed
make: *** [mycompiler] Error 1
```

Oddly enough those should be in the LLVMSupport library which is being included.

My Makefile:

```
all: mycompiler

LLVMCONFIG = llvm-config
CPPFLAGS = `$(LLVMCONFIG) --cxxflags` -v
LDFLAGS = `$(LLVMCONFIG) --ldflags` -v -rdynamic
LIBS = `$(LLVMCONFIG) --libs --system-libs`

LEGACY_FLEX_WARNS = -Wno-deprecated-register

OBJECTS = mycompiler.lexer.o  \
          mycompiler.parser.o \
          mycompiler.driver.o \
          mycompiler.codegen.o

mycompiler.parser.hpp: mycompiler.parser.cpp

mycompiler.parser.cpp: mycompiler.y
    bison -d $^ --verbose --report=all --report-file=bison_report

mycompiler.lexer.cpp: mycompiler.l mycompiler.parser.hpp
    flex  mycompiler.l

%.o: %.cpp
    clang++ $(LEGACY_FLEX_WARNS) -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

mycompiler: $(OBJECTS)
    clang++ -g $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.bc *~ *.output
    rm -f mycompiler.lexer.cpp mycompiler.lexer.hpp mycompiler.parser.cpp mycompiler.parser.hpp
    rm -f mycompiler bison_report
```

You will notice that I am including `-v` for verbose output so I can see all the libs and such being included by llvm-config.  I have actually tried several different build parameters already, but just end up with even more linker issues.

Here is an example verbose output from the full build:

```
bison -d mycompiler.y --verbose --report=all --report-file=bison_report
flex  mycompiler.l
clang++ -Wno-deprecated-register -c mycompiler.lexer.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags` -v -o mycompiler.lexer.o
clang version 3.9.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 7658b570923dcdfaaec04d837b7e8862eff895f8) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4edb79d2d975816fee53b814703812b2287ed455)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/clang-3.9" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name mycompiler.lexer.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-file /home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.lexer.o -resource-dir /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0 -I /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include -D _GNU_SOURCE -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1 -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wno-deprecated-register -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Werror=date-time -pedantic -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/storage/data/mycompiler -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-rtti -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o mycompiler.lexer.o -x c++ mycompiler.lexer.cpp
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'; did you mean '-Wno-uninitialized'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
clang -cc1 version 3.9.0 based upon LLVM 3.9.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
mycompiler.l:393:12: warning: unused function 'isValidChar' [-Wunused-function]
static int isValidChar(const char c)
           ^
2 warnings generated.
clang++ -Wno-deprecated-register -c mycompiler.parser.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags` -v -o mycompiler.parser.o
clang version 3.9.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 7658b570923dcdfaaec04d837b7e8862eff895f8) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4edb79d2d975816fee53b814703812b2287ed455)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/clang-3.9" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name mycompiler.parser.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-file /home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.parser.o -resource-dir /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0 -I /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include -D _GNU_SOURCE -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1 -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wno-deprecated-register -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Werror=date-time -pedantic -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/storage/data/mycompiler -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-rtti -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o mycompiler.parser.o -x c++ mycompiler.parser.cpp
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'; did you mean '-Wno-uninitialized'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
clang -cc1 version 3.9.0 based upon LLVM 3.9.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
1 warning generated.
clang++ -Wno-deprecated-register -c mycompiler.driver.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags` -v -o mycompiler.driver.o
clang version 3.9.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 7658b570923dcdfaaec04d837b7e8862eff895f8) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4edb79d2d975816fee53b814703812b2287ed455)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/clang-3.9" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name mycompiler.driver.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-file /home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.driver.o -resource-dir /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0 -I /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include -D _GNU_SOURCE -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1 -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wno-deprecated-register -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Werror=date-time -pedantic -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/storage/data/mycompiler -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-rtti -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o mycompiler.driver.o -x c++ mycompiler.driver.cpp
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'; did you mean '-Wno-uninitialized'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
clang -cc1 version 3.9.0 based upon LLVM 3.9.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
mycompiler.driver.cpp:99:15: warning: unused variable 'output' [-Wunused-variable]
        FILE *output = yyget_out(myscanner); // TODO: where do we want to redirect this?
              ^
2 warnings generated.
clang++ -Wno-deprecated-register -c mycompiler.codegen.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags` -v -o mycompiler.codegen.o
clang version 3.9.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 7658b570923dcdfaaec04d837b7e8862eff895f8) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4edb79d2d975816fee53b814703812b2287ed455)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/clang-3.9" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name mycompiler.codegen.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-file /home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.o -resource-dir /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0 -I /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include -D _GNU_SOURCE -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1 -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wno-deprecated-register -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Werror=date-time -pedantic -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/storage/data/mycompiler -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-rtti -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o mycompiler.codegen.o -x c++ mycompiler.codegen.cpp
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'; did you mean '-Wno-uninitialized'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
clang -cc1 version 3.9.0 based upon LLVM 3.9.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
1 warning generated.
clang++ -g mycompiler.lexer.o mycompiler.parser.o mycompiler.driver.o mycompiler.codegen.o `llvm-config --ldflags` -v -rdynamic `llvm-config --link-static --libs --system-libs` -o mycompiler
clang version 3.9.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 7658b570923dcdfaaec04d837b7e8862eff895f8) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4edb79d2d975816fee53b814703812b2287ed455)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o mycompiler /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/crtbegin.o -L/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/lib -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../.. -L/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib mycompiler.lexer.o mycompiler.parser.o mycompiler.driver.o mycompiler.codegen.o -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMPasses -lLLVMCoverage -lLLVMOrcJIT -lLLVMObjectYAML -lLLVMMIRParser -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMSymbolize -lLLVMDebugInfoPDB -lLLVMDebugInfoDWARF -lLLVMLibDriver -lLLVMOption -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMSparcAsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmParser -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMBPFCodeGen -lLLVMBPFDesc -lLLVMBPFInfo -lLLVMBPFAsmPrinter -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler -lLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMObject -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUDesc -lLLVMAMDGPUInfo -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter -lLLVMAMDGPUUtils -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMGlobalISel -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMDebugInfoCodeView -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMCore -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMSupport -lrt -ldl -lcurses -lpthread -lz -lm -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/crtend.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `CodeGenContext':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:59: undefined reference to `llvm::sys::getProcessTriple()'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `CodeGenContext::handleError(int, int, llvm::StringRef, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:87: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `CompilationUnit::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2200: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `NamespaceDeclarationNode::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2220: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `UsingDeclarationNode::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2226: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o: In function `Int8Node::debugPrintInternal(std::ostream&, CodeGenContext&, llvm::Twine const&)':
/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2237: undefined reference to `llvm::Twine::str() const'
mycompiler.codegen.o:/home/storage/data/mycompiler/mycompiler.codegen.cpp:2242: more undefined references to `llvm::Twine::str() const' follow
clang-3.9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'mycompiler' failed
make: *** [mycompiler] Error 1
```

Note that I am currently including all LLVM components by simply using the `--libs` parameter to `llvm-config`.  I have tried to modify this as well by just selecting the various components I needed with the same results.

The `warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized';` is also new in this version of LLVM apparently as I wasn't getting that warn before.

I'm sure this is possible on Arch as one of the searches I found with similar errors was on the [Arch Wiki](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114614), but you can see that I am already following that advice that was answered on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207734/trouble-linking-against-llvm-with-project-including-flex-and-bison).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

For those that are interested some relevant information can be found in the following links:

- [llvm-config
  information](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html)
- [llvm CMake install](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html)

Comment: Looks like `libLLVMSupport` is missing. Make sure that you've built it and it's in a correct place.

Comment: I originally expected that, but libLLVMSupport.a was built and -lLLVMSupport is being passed by llvm-config.  I did read an outdated page on the LLVM site that mentioned not needing to link against both .a and .o IIRC.  I will verify again... any other ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure I ran `llvm-config --libfiles` to see the path for the libs and `/home/storage/data/build_llvm/build/llvm/lib/libLLVMSupport.a` is being passed in.  I did actually run a test by passing exactly what `llvm-config --libs` would output minus  the Support library and had WAY more errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great...

So this appears to be a bug with ABI incompatability between GCC 5.0 and Clang. :(

More information [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92629) and the open [bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529).

I can fix easily for now by switching from clang++ to g++ in my Makefile.

Funny thing is g++ seems to build WAY faster then clang ever was.  I'm talking orders of magnitude faster.