# Binding against LLVM 3.8.4 no getGlobalContext

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am attempting to follow the https://github.com/lsegal/my_toy_compiler, but even though it has been updated for LLVM 3.8.0, I am unable to get it to compile using LLVM 3.8.4 from brew with `--with-clang --with-lld --with-jit --with-python`. Specifically I get the following error, `use of undeclared identifier 'getGlobalContext'`.

Additionally the symbol `getGlobalContext` does not appear in the `/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h` or indeed anywhere in the `/usr/local/opt/llvm/include` directory.

I expect that either this function has been deprecated recently, (for which I have not been able to find any evidence), or that I am not building it correctly.

Any tips would be appreciated.

**NOTE** I have seen [Trouble linking against LLVM with project including Flex and Bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207734/trouble-linking-against-llvm-with-project-including-flex-and-bison) and it did not resolve my particular problem

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered the same problem with llvm 4.0.
My solution is as follows.

old:

```
LLVMContext *llvmcx;
llvmcx = &getGlobalContext();
```

new:

```
LLVMContext *llvmcx;
static LLVMContext MyGlobalContext;
llvmcx = &MyGlobalContext;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with 4.0.0 version built from svn. I've found the following commit 266379 with the removing all occurrences of getGlobalConfig()

https://reviews.llvm.org/rL266379

This commit changes examples either defining internal context variable:
*Was*:

```
static IRBuilder<> Builder(getGlobalContext());
```

*Become*:

```
static LLVMContext TheContext;
static IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);
```

Comment: Thanks. I should mention that I was able to solve my issue by just building the latest zips from source (version 3.8.something), but this is good information as well.